# CMake Extensions - VS-Code: Set up workflow where CMake opens a dialogue for me to choose a source dir whenever I click on build

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, vscode-extensions

I'm right now working on a Project integrating zephyr within a repository using CMake extensions.

The repository has following dir structure:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTgE2.png)

Now whenever I want to change the source directory, I have to reset the cmake.sourceDirectory manually by writting to the setting.json file.

I wanted to ask, if someone knows an better approach. I was thinking on setting up a workflow where CMake opens a dialogue for me to choose a source dir whenever I click on build.

Thx all for the help!

I searched for on how to introduce vars to settings.json(there is no way?).

I was thinking on creating a task, but well then I don't know exactly on how to get CMake to reopning the browse windows for the sourceDir.

Comment: if you can do it with a task you can use the extension I wrote: [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#pick-file) and use the command `extension.commandvariable.file.pickFile` to show a file/directory picker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake Tools supports specifying multiple source directories in the `cmake.sourceDirectory` [setting](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/cmake-settings.md#cmake-settings). It can take a string (path to single source directory), or an array of strings (array of paths to source directories). Ex. `"cmake.sourceDirectory": ["${workspaceFolder}/1", "${workspaceFolder}/2"]`. Then you can switch between source directories by using the `CMake: Select Active Folder` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette).

Note also that CMake Tools supports [multi-root workspaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces) if you want to go that route.